# What is this derivative rule/theorem/property called?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

For expressions like $x^2+2x+5$, there is an easy trick to find the derivative.

> You change the exponent of the first term to the coefficient and subtract 1 from the exponent, so you get $2x$.
>
> Then you do the same for the second, and you get $2$
>
> So the derivative is $2x+2$

What is this theorem/rule/property called?

Comment: Power rule. Together with sum rule.

Comment: Also the constant multiple rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Thanks to @littleO for correcting me)

The rule to calculate the derivative of $x^n $ is called the "power rule" but it is just an immediate consequence of the definition of derivative. One can derive the formula

$$(\alpha x^n)^\prime = n\alpha x^{n-1} $$

By using the derivative's definition with the limit

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{ f(a + h) - f(a)}{h} $$

where $f(x) = \alpha x^n $

If you are to try, maybe start with natural values of $n $.

This rule is so elementary that one can readily use it in exercises, tests, etc without having to name it, since one is expected to have this rule "on the tip of their tongue".

Along with the property that the derivative of the sum is the sum of the derivatives:

$$(f + g)^\prime = f^\prime + g^\prime $$

Enables you to differentiate any expression like that.